# Getting errors trying to install RVM on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, rvm

What else can I try?

```
user15:~ durrantm$ bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
user15:~ durrantm$ cat .bash_profile 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
user15:~ durrantm$ type rvm | head -n1
-bash: type: rvm: not found
user15:~ durrantm$ rvm -v
-bash: rvm: command not found
user15:~ durrantm$
```

Also this did not help...

`sudo gem install rvm -s http://gemcutter.org/
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302 fetching http://gemcutter.org/yaml
users-powerbook-g4-15:~ durrantm$`

Comment: did you close and reopen your terminal?

Comment: which version are you trying to install? latest?

Comment: yes i reopened.  Yes the latest version. How do I specify previous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo rm -rf $HOME/rvm-installer $HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvmrc /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm /usr/local/bin/rvm*

sudo rm -f /usr/local/share/man/man1/rvm.1*

bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )

echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile

logout
```

Log back in then execute

```
type rvm | head -n1
```

which should return

rvm is a function

You should now be able to use RVM with no issues. Please see https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ and the additional documentation there for how to work with gemsets and to install additional rubies and the like. have fun!

Answer (score 0):

worked for me before. could be a problem with the latest RVM release... try the previous RVM version

looks like you made the modifications to .bashrc which are required for RVM? After you make these changes, **you will need to start a new Bash shell** , e.g. open a new terminal window

Comment: yes i opened a new shell.  How do i specify version?

Comment: sorry, i was on my iPad.. let me check...